# Validate the Email which added in the URL in Laravel with using laravel validation rule only

Tags: php, laravel

I am working in Laravel.

I have a URL like as below:

```
http://localhost/udonls/public/mastercandidate/candidate/reset-password/11/das@sdadas.com
```

Now has a function which is like

```
public function sendCanResLink(Request $request, $id, $email) 
{
       // So in this function how should i validate "$email" using laravel validation ?
}
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('/candidate/reset-password/{id}/{email}', [
   'as'    => 'candidate.reset.password',
   'uses'  => 'CandidateSmdnContoller@sendCanResLink'
]);
```

**Overall !! I want to validate my email address which I get in the GET request in larvae with Laravel validation.**

I know `regex` technique but I want to use the Laravel validation technique.

Comment: First you have to change the route method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
 public function sendCanResLink(Request $request, $id, $email) 
 {
    try {
         $validator = Validator::make(compact('email'), [
            "email" => "required|email:rfc,dns,filter,spoof",
         ])->validate();
    } catch(ValidationException $validation) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I will try this solution and back with the result

Comment: Did it work?
Also have you tried to throw that exception to be perfectly sure that it did work as intended?

Comment: It definitely works, I have just tried as of 04/2022. But for the DNS part, ti checks only if that domain exists, if the account doesn't, still passes, but, better than nothing or complex regexes.

Comment: You are referring to this: https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator/blob/master/src/Validation/DNSCheckValidation.php  ?
Well, I'll look for a solution for the account "check", If I find something I'll edit the solution

Comment: This is a paid service (but the pricing is actually nice) : https://www.emaillistverify.com/

Answer (score 2):

Why spend resources on validation in this case, if you can check one on one for the user?

```
Route::get('/candidate/reset-password/{user}/{email}', [
   'as'    => 'candidate.reset.password',
   'uses'  => 'CandidateSmdnContoller@sendCanResLink'
]);

public function sendCanResLink(Request $request, User $user, $email) 
{
   if($user->email !== $email) return 'some error';

   // reset code here

   return 'ok'; 
}
```

2) With validator

```
public function sendCanResLink(Request $request, $id, $email) 
{
   Validator::make(compact('email'), [
       'email' => ['required', 'string', 'regex:/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/', 'max:255', 'unique:YOUR_TABLE']
   ])->validate();
  // auto redirect back if error and use 
  // @error('email') {{ $message }} @enderror in blade 
}
```

Comment: Actually i was updating the email also and here the latest mail is not yet updated but added in the form so talking direct email form the form.

Comment: @always-a-learner I added a second method as you want. he still checks the uniqueness in the database